# how to fetch specific and unique data from database different tables in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i want to fetch data from database three tables all are linked together.
I'm facing problem, i have tried many methods to it like `merge, unique and separate list`.
following is the code.

```
<?php
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","db");

$rows=$conn->query("select Account,Amount, event_name,event_description from donations
                    LEFT JOIN accounts
                    ON accounts.ID_Account=donations.ID_Account
                    LEFT JOIN events
                    ON events.event_id=donations.event_id ");
$rows1=$conn->query("SELECT Account from accounts");

while((list($Account, $Amount, $event_name,$event_description)=$rows->fetch_row()) and (list($Account)=$rows1->fetch_row()))
{   
echo "<tr><td> $Account</td><td> $Amount </td><td>$event_name</td><td>$event_description</td></tr>";    
}   
?>
```

Now The problem is, it shows duplicate data from accounts and also I want it to be like if there is no donation `$Amount` for the account `$Account` it should not show donation in front of `Account`, but it is showing. is there any way i can make it working the way i want?
Many Thanks.

Comment: E.g. if there are several events for one account, you will get several rows for that account - is that what you get?

Comment: I get the random data like it shows all donation whether it belongs to that account or not, i want the data like **Account->its Donation->Event** and if there is no donation for the Account then Only Account should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for some data hydration methods. Now you will get A * B * C = X rows with your resulting data because you are doing multiple joins and your resulting array from mysql will always have only one dimension and therefore a lot of duplicated data.

What you want is array (or object) with more than one dimension. I assume you want a resulting array with something like:

```
$result = array(
    'account1' => array('event1', 'event2'),
    'account1' => array('event3', 'event4', 'event5')
);
```

There are multiple solutions to this:

1. Write your own data hydration method to create a new array with values from your result
2. Do three single queries instead of one query with JOIN, then merge the results (can even be faster!)
3. Use doctrine (a php database abstraction layer) which can do exactly what you want without too much trouble.

If you start to code new app I would recommend 3.) to you:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Comment: thanks i will try them, let you know.
btw from the above code  
I get the random data like it shows all donation whether it belongs to that account or not, i want the data like **Account->its Donation->Event** and if there is no donation for the Account then Only **Account** should be shown.

Comment: i have tried the second method, but result is same i.e random data.

Comment: while 1 and 3 difficult to understand.  Though i will try 1 and 3 later, I need something easy and reliable at the moment.

Comment: Can you post your three tables that you use?